# Euclidean algorithm as a linear combination substitution and simplifying

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This problem is from my discrete mathematics textbook.

I'm trying to find $\gcd(420,66)$

I compute
$$\begin{align*}
420 &= 6 \times 66 + 24\\
66 &= 2\times 24 + 18\\
24 &= 1 \times 18 + 6\\
18 &= 3 \times 6 + 0
\end{align*}$$
then I rewrite the equation 
$$\begin{align*}
6 &= 24 - 1 \times 18\\
18 &= 66 - 2 \times 24\\
24 &= 420 - 6 \times 66\\
\end{align*}$$

Now I try to perform substitutions which give me 
$$\begin{align*}
6 &= 24 -1 \times 18\\
& = 24-1 (66 - 2 \times 24)\\
&= 3 \times 24 -66
\end{align*}$$

My question is how do you transition from 
$$    24-1  (66 - 2 \times 24)$$ 
to
$$3 \times 24 -66$$

I just can't wrap my head around this part. Maybe I'm way over thinking this step.

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: $\: y -1\:(x - 2\:y)\ =\ y -x + 2\:y\ =\ 3\:y - x.\ $ Yours is the special case $\: y=24, x = 66.\:$ The law $a(b+c)\: =\ ab + ac$ is known as the *distributive law*.

Comment: The distributive law: $24-1(66-2\cdot 24) = 24 + (-1)66+(2)24 = (1+2)24+(-1)66=(3)24+(-1)66$.

Comment: For quickly checking your work: http://www.math.sc.edu/~sumner/numbertheory/euclidean/euclidean.html

Comment: Back substitution is painful manually. Easier is to augment an idenity matrix to keep track of the elimination operations, just as in linear algebra. For a detailed work example see my [answer here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242)

Comment: Thanks guys this is makes since now!

Comment: See the [Euclidean algorithm in matrix form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Matrix_method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distribute, reorder, associate:
$$\begin{align*}
24 - 1(66-2\times 24) &= 24 -1(66) -1(-2\times 24)\\
&= 24 - 66 +2\times 24\\
&= 24 + 2\times 24 - 66\\
&= (1+2)24 - 66\\
&= 3\times 24 - 66.
\end{align*}$$